# React Native function in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a (probably) very simple question:

I am trying to call the function *handleRequest* as soon as the button *Logout* is pressed, but I am getting an error that the *undefined is not an object*. I think, I need to rearrange the functions, but I am not sure how, as I am new to React Native.

Hopefully someone can help me.

All the best
Nader

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Button } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    return <View>
        <Text>Home</Text>
        <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
            title='Login'
        />
        <Text></Text>
        <Button
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Register')}
            title='Register'
        />
        <Text></Text>
        <View>
            <Button title="Logout" onPress={this.handleRequest.bind(this)} />
        </View>
    </View>
}



const handleRequest = () => {
    axios
        .get('http://192.168.0.213:8000/api/auth/logout/')
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            Actions.auth()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
}

export default HomeScreen
```

Comment: what is `Actions` inside `then` of `handleRequest` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call by this :

```
onPress={()=>handleRequest()}
```

always remember this or bind are class property

Answer (score 2):

change button to

```js
<Button title="Logout" onPress={handleRequest} />
```

`this` is not needed in functional components. also consider moving `handleRequest` function above or inside `HomeScreen`.

Other possible issues are missing imports to axios and `Actions`.